# Кодировка в ajax - Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, java-ee, spring-mvc

Всем привет!
Возникла такая проблема. У меня есть jsp страница, на которой форма добавления предмета и список со всеми предметами. Вывожу я весь список так: в контроллере ложу в модель список объектов и на странице вывожу его с помощью jstl:

```
<table border=2 bgcolor="#C1CDCD" id="subjectsTableResponse">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><B>Предмет</B></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${subjectList}" var="subject">
            <c:if test="${subject.deleted eq false}">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">${subject.title}</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a href="<c:url value='/subject/update/${subject.id}' />">Редактировать</a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a href="<c:url value='/subject/delete/${subject.id}' />">Удалить</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Обратите внимание, что в ссылке на редактирование и удаление объекта в фигурных скобках сетится id предмета, по которому в дальнейшем можно редактировать предмет или удалить.

**Вот мой скрипт, которой добавляет предмет в список:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#saveSubject').submit(function (e) {
    $.post('/university/subjectAdd', $(this).serialize(), function (subject) {
        $('#subjectsTableResponse').last().append(
            '<tr>' +
            '<td align=\"center\">' + subject.title + '</td>' +
            '<td align=\"center\">' + '<a href=\"<c:url value=\'/subject/update/{'+subject.id+'}\'/>">' + 'Редактировать' + '</a>'+'</td>'+
            '<td align=\"center\">' + '<a href=\"<c:url value=\'/subject/delete/{'+subject.id+'}\'/>">' + 'Удалить' + '</a>'+'</td>'+
            '</tr>'
        );
    });
});
});
```

Когда я просто пытаюсь редактировать объект или удалить, все ок, контроллер тянет id и производит  необходимую операцию, пример:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/student/delete/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView studentDelete(@PathVariable Long id){
    Student student = studentService.findById(id);
    student.setDeleted(true);
    studentService.update(student);
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/university/students"));
}
```

Теперь суть проблемы. Когда я только добавил новый предмет в список и решил его сразу (то есть без перезагрузки страницы) редактировать или удалить, то вылазит ошибка, следующего содержания:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/url%20value='/subject/delete/%7B160%7D'%3E%3C/a%3E
```

Если, я перезагружу страницу, то все отрабатывает ок, видимо контроллер сам преобразовывает к нужному виду.

**Сам вопрос, как пофиксить ?)**

Comment: <c:url> - это конструкция jstl, обрабатываемая на стороне сервера. Попытка использовать её на стороне клиента приводит к ошибке, так как браузер не знает такого тега и уж тем более не ожидает увидеть его в атрибуте href.

Comment: Не подскажете, как тогда правильно вписывать ссылку в ответе ?

Comment: `'<a href="/subject/update/' + subject.id + '">Редактировать</a>'`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<c:url>` - это конструкция JSTL, обрабатываемая на стороне сервера. Попытка использовать её на стороне клиента приводит к ошибке, так как браузер не знает такого тега и уж тем более не ожидает увидеть его в атрибуте href. Используйте в коде javascript простую конкатенацию:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#saveSubject').submit(function(e) {
        $.post('/university/subjectAdd', $(this).serialize(), function (subject) {
            $('#subjectsTableResponse').last().append(
                '<tr>' +
                '<td align="center">' + subject.title + '</td>' +
                '<td align="center"><a href="/subject/update/' + subject.id + '">' + 'Редактировать' + '</a></td>' +
                '<td align="center"><a href="/subject/delete/' + subject.id + '">' + 'Удалить' + '</a></td>' +
                '</tr>'
            );
        });
    });
});
```

**P.S.** Судя по выражению `$('#subjectsTableResponse').last()` у вас в документе несколько элементов с одинаковым id. Это неправильно и может приводить к ошибкам, id должны быть уникальны.